# get Value from a div tag

Tags: javascript

I have the following situation and I know have a lot of this subject here in stackoverflow, but no answers give a real solution, so I'm posting again.

First take a look at this code:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Estado</td><td>
        <select name="estado" onChange="javascript:Atualiza(this.value,'0');">
            <option>[selecione]</option>
            <?
            $qry = "SELECT nome, uf FROM tb_estados"; 
            $res = mysql_query($qry);
            while ($ln = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { 
                echo "<option value='$ln[uf]'>".$ln['nome']."</option>"; 
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and Now at this piece of code

```
<tr>
     <td align="right">Cidade</td>
     <td><div id="atualiza"></div></td>
</tr>
```

I have a linked combo, to show states and cities.

**Now my problem:**
I can not get the value from my `<div id="atualiza">` the values of `<select name="estado"` no problem cause it is an object of my form but the div tag is not an object of the form. 
I need to `INSERT INTO`  my database the value of `<div id="atualiza">`

**How to do this?**

I would like to save the value inside an hidden field and send in my form to insert in my database.

I had a similar situation before and I solved the problem, but it was so bizarre and I know there is an easy way to do that.

**The Atualiza function**

```
function Atualiza(valor,cid) 
{ 
    loadXMLDoc("combo_cidade.php",valor,cid); 
}
```

**Also my page combo_cidade.php**

```
<?php 
echo "<select name='cidade' id='cidade'>"; 
echo "<option>[selecione]</option>"; 

# my databse connection
include_once("config/config.php");

$sql = "SELECT tb_cidades.nome, tb_cidades.id FROM tb_cidades INNER JOIN tb_estados ON tb_cidades.uf=tb_estados.uf WHERE tb_cidades.uf='".$_GET["uf"]."'";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql); 
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){ 
    if ($_GET["cid"]==$linha["id"]){$sel="selected";}else{$sel="";}
    echo "<option value='$linha[id]' $sel>$linha[nome]</option>"; 
} 
echo "</select>"; 


?>
```

**Here goes the whole script that handle my combo**

```
// JavaScript Document
var req; 

function loadXMLDoc(url,valor,cid) 
{ 
    req = null; 
    // Procura por um objeto nativo (Mozilla/Safari) 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange; 
        req.open("GET", url+'?uf='+valor+'&cid='+cid, true); 
        req.send(null); 
    // Procura por uma versao ActiveX (IE) 
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        if (req) { 
            req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange; 
            req.open("GET", url+'?uf='+valor+'&cid='+cid, true); 
            req.send(); 
        } 
    } 
} 

function processReqChange() 
{ 
    // apenas quando o estado for "completado" 
    if (req.readyState == 4) { 
        // apenas se o servidor retornar "OK" 
        if (req.status == 200) { 
            // procura pela div id="atualiza" e insere o conteudo 
            // retornado nela, como texto HTML 
            document.getElementById('atualiza').innerHTML = req.responseText;           
        } else { 
            alert("Houve um problema ao obter os dados:\n" + req.statusText); 
        } 
    } 
} 

function Atualiza(valor,cid) 
{ 
    loadXMLDoc("combo_cidade.php",valor,cid); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this JS code in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddHiddenValue(oForm) {
   var strValue = document.getElementById("atualiza").innerHTML;
   var oHidden = document.createElement("input");
   oHidden.name = "atualiza";
   oHidden.value = strValue;
   oForm.appendChild(oHidden);
}
</script>
```

Then have this in the form tag:

```
<form ... onsubmit="AddHiddenValue(this);">
```

And finally read the value of "atualiza" from the request in your PHP code.

Comment: not work, it puts a ZERO value in my table. But I think is the way.. Thanks anyway..

Comment: my idea is to get the value from div and put it in my hidden field. Is there an easy way to do? Impossible to be very painful and hard like this, is just a simple value, a simple field.. still searching a solution..

Comment: @Fernando sorry that's the way, you did something wrong. Let's try to debug it step by step. After this line: `var strValue = document.getElementById("atualiza").innerHTML;` add this new line: `alert("value: " + strValue);` what do you see when submitting the form?

Comment: @Shadow when I submit I got this =>  value: <select name="cidade" id="cidade"><option>[selecione]</option><option value="0001">Acrelandia</option><option value="0002">Assis Brasil</option><option value="0003">Brasileia</option>  AND a lot of another options ... what do you think is going wrong, the atualiza has a value, but a value of everything from my city table. If i get only the selected the problem is solved.. thanks for help anyway.

Comment: @Fernando OK, so your DIV contains lots of things. What exactly you want to send? The selected value of "cidade" drop down?

Comment: @Shadow that's right I want to send only the selected value of my "cidade" drop down. But I have no skills in JJS..

Comment: @Fernando so change this `var strValue = document.getElementById("atualiza").innerHTML;` to this: `var strValue = document.getElementById("cidade").value;` however you should be able to read this directly from within PHP..

Comment: I need to put in my database only the code of city like 9007, but unlike it is inserted the whole content of my drop down --- like this <select name="cidade" id="cidade"><option>[selecione]</option><option value="0275">Abacate da Pedreira</option><option value="0276">Agua Branca do Amapari</option><option value="0277">Amapa</option><option value="0278">Amapari</option><option value="0279"

Comment: @Shadow I was thinking if is possible to have a kind of selected option somewhere inside this -> document.getElementById("atualiza").innerHTML;

Comment: @Shadow wow man, this line var strValue = document.getElementById("cidade").value; solve the problem!!! Work perfectly!!!! 
Thank You very much. I gave a vote up for you and the accepted answer also. Really thanks.

Comment: @Fernando glad it's finally working, could have solved this long time ago if I understood you're after the selected value of that drop down.. :/

Comment: @Shadow Yeah man, I did the whole script long time ago, and It never worked properly, because the value of that div tag, but now with your expertise everything is OKAY. :-]

Comment: @Fernando cheers, I hope you've learned from this as well - your own skills should be better now. :)

Comment: @Shadow, Is always gratifying when we learn something well, it will be very usefull from now on.. Also I got the answer for something I was so long time searching and nobody give an answer.. Great!

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, `value` attribute is used in form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`. If you want to get the "value" of a DIV element (I mean what is written inside that tag), you can use the `innerHTML` attribute. For example, consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="d">Hello</div>
```

Now `document.getElementById('d').innerHTML` will return "Hello".

Getting back to your code, when you send the AJAX request, u get a `<select name='cidade' id='cidade'>...` text and set that as `innerHTML` of the `DIV` tag. You can get the selected value in the inner `select` using `document.getElementById('cidade').value` and set the value of your hidden `input` to that value, because when u set that string as the `innerHTML` of the `DIV` tag, that will be parsed and converted to a normal `select` tag inside that `DIV`, i.e.

```
<tr>
     <td align="right">Cidade</td>
     <td><div id="atualiza"><select name='cidade' id='cidade'><option>...</select></div></td>
</tr>
```

**Conclusion:**

Put a hidden `input` with name `cidade` somewhere **inside** your form:

```
<form ...>
...
<input type="hidden" name="cidade" id="cidade_input" value="" />
```

and set its value when the value of the `select` changes:

```
combo_cidade.php, line 2:
echo "<select name='cidade' id='cidade' onchange='f1(this.value);'>";

in your JavaScript:
function f1(value) {
    document.getElementById('cidade_input').value = value;
}
```

or when the form is submitting:

```
your form tag:
<form ... onsubmit="f2()">

in JavaScript:
function f2() {
    document.getElementById('cidade_input').value = document.getElementById('cidade').value;
}
```

**Some notes on your code:**

In your php file `combo_cidade.php`, on line 8, you should not use the value given in the request ($_GET) directly. This can lead to a SQL Injection in your code. Instead, you should use [addslashes function](http://www.php.net/addslashes) (or [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) as highly recommended in the PHP manual) to prevent SQL Injection attacks on your site. That will be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT tb_cidades.nome, tb_cidades.id FROM tb_cidades INNER JOIN tb_estados ON tb_cidades.uf=tb_estados.uf WHERE tb_cidades.uf='".addslashes($_GET["uf"])."'";
```

Another note: It is better to use double quotation for HTML attribute values other than single quotes. You can change your second line of PHP code to this:

```
echo '<select name="cidade" id="cidade" onchange="f1(this.value);">';
```

And the last note: You don't need to have `name` attribute in the echo'ed `select`, because it is not in a form and that attribute will be useless. Therefore it will be like this:

```
echo '<select id="cidade" onchange="f1(this.value);">';
```

and if you use the `onchange` and not `onsubmit` (i.e. setting the hidden `input` value when the combo changes, not when the form is submitted), the `id` attribute is useless too. That will change it to:

```
echo '<select onchange="f1(this.value);">';
```

Comment: If `div` contains bolded text then `innerHTML` returns `<b>text</b>` (example).

Comment: I have Updated my post with function Atualiza() and also my page combo_cidade.php ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in javascript).

```
var value = document.getElementById("atualiza").firstChild.nodeValue;
```

or

```
var value = document.getElementById("atualiza").innerText;
```

As to how to include that (javascript) into PHP, I'm not in that league (as yet).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the select in a form? You can have more than one form in a page if you need to.